# How to save memory After using UITableView iphone

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks

I am Using UITableView with reuse identifier it is taking to much Memory After creating some more cell
whenever i increase the count of cell in table row it takes more memory.
Is there any trick by which i can save memory.

Comment: can you post the code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

Comment: Sir actully i have correct code but whenever i scroll my app take more memory:for example If my tableview is showing 8 cells ,when i scroll its take some more memory , i want some smart tips by which i can save memory

Comment: your code isn't correct if you consume more and more memory if you scroll through a tableview

Comment: Are you sure that your are using the reuse identifier the right way and don't have a typo? Are you dequeuing your new cell. Posting your code would help.